# Installing a .NET assembly into GAC using MSI

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, installshield, gac

I wish to install a `.NET` `assembly` into the GAC using a Setup project, `MSI`. While I have a general idea on how to go about it, does the `assembly` need to be signed before the `MSI` installs it, and if so, in a production environment, how is the `assembly` supposed to get signed?

i.e. what can I set up on `Visual Studio` /`InstallShield` to sign the assembly automatically, and then install it via the `MSI` on the target machine `GAC`?

Also, if I uninstall the application, would the assembly loaded in the`GAC,` be removed as well?

Do help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Publishing an assembly to the GAC requires that the assembly have a [strong name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad.aspx). This is a form of signing that does not use traditional certificate-authority based digital certificates. InstallShield, at least, offers no particular suppport for applying a strong name to an assembly, but Visual Studio offers the option to do so from within the project.

Once your assembly has a strong name, it can be installed to the GAC. Once the MSI is configured correctly (assuming you're using an MSI), it will remove it (or at least decrement the reference count) on uninstallation.

Comment: So, in a production environment, how can I integrate this? i.e., create a strongly named key, and then apply it on a file? The point is that the files are also externally and internally signed using certificates, and whether there would be any conflicts? Also, how can the process be automated?

Comment: @user1173240 You must strong name the assembly before applying an authenticode signature. These two kinds of digital signatures [accomplish two different goals](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/03/what-s-the-difference-part-five-certificate-signing-vs-strong-naming.aspx). Anyway, just read the linked MSDN article, and implement the one it links on [how to sign an assembly with a strong name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx). If you also need authenticode signatures, InstallShield can apply those (Releases view > Signing tab). Or ask a new question.